# Adding diffrent hyperlinks to each row in Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, hyperlink, report, action

So I need to add different hyperlinks on each generated row. What I mean, I have SQL query to select some data like this:

```
Name                      Description
First       First should be clickable and open www.url1.com
Second      Second - open www.url2.com
Third       Third- open www.url3.com
....
```

SQL query:

```
-- this is example query, just for explaining idea
    SELECT F.Name        AS Name, 
           T.Description AS Description
    FROM   Forms         AS F
    INNER JOIN Tasks     AS T
        ON F.Id = T.FormId
```

For example here are 2 columns `Name` and `Description` which are selected via SQL query. It selecting all needed rows from tables. How can I add specific hyperlinks on each selected row?

For now Report Design looks like:
[image: report design]

After I select `[Name] > Properties > Action` It pop-up `Text Box Properties`
[image: action]

If I select Go to URL I can type any URL I want, but will be the same for all rows in the `Name` column, how to make It different for each row?

**EDIT**

Description about `Name` column, each row should open different URL. But these rows are selected only in `Report Preview`

[image: name column]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the URL using the expression. On click of the expression button pop up will be open and then you can select the your field as the value. And then set the expression as

[image]

```
  =Fields!Description.Value
```

If you want to pass some argument with it you can concat with actual value.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. But how It will work? As you see in my first image here are 2 column names: `Name` and `Description`.  And rows are generated after `Perview Report` button is clicked. I need to make for each row to open different URL. So I need to add expression something like: `=Fields!Name.First`? But how to add multiple `URLS` for  multiple rows? I mean  `=Fields!Name.First(www.url1.com); =Fields!Name.Second(url2.com)` How should syntax look like?

Comment: I am confused. You want to set seprate `Description` as URL  to open for the each `Name` right. If thats the case then do just what i said in answer . No need to do anything else. The SSRS will handle the mapping of each name to its relative `Discription` URL.

Comment: SSRS will handle the URL mapping just set them in expression.

Comment: No really, doesnt matter what are in `Description` field. I just gave you for example to understand what should name rows do (in reality here are other data in `Names` and `Description`. I need to make each of name clickable and each name should open different URL.

Comment: I got that, But `SSRS` handles mapping of URL as long as you have valid URL for each name you just need to set the action link. It will process same as it does when mapping name or id for each row with other data of that row.Try this you will understand what I am talking about.

Comment: I've edited my question with image how Name column should look like

Comment: No, only Name, Description and Count Id, It dont have column with URL. But as I understood in your method I need to create 1 mpore column wich will hold URLS of each row, true?

Comment: Ohh Yes. I thought you already had that column in dataset. As you mentioned in you r question.

Comment: No, I just in description field tryied to explain what `Name` column should do. In real Description hold other information, nothing about URLs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70548/discussion-between-coder-of-code-and-infinity).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add the URL you want to be associated with each row as a field in your database, and you can then just set the URL field in Actions in Textbox properties to `=Fields!URL.Value`, or whatever you call the new field in your DB

The alternative would be a long-ass Switch() statement coupled with either the Field Name or RowNumber() to make the Action be the URL you need.

EDIT: Coder of Code gave the same answer, I missed that somehow so this is a duplicate, sorry about that.

Comment: Did you read the question description he already mentioned the URL is coming from the query ? So why should use the `switch()`or `rownumber`

Comment: Where? He mentions that the URL is a part of the description field, but not a separate field that I can see. EDIT - I did miss your answer though, which is of course the same as mine, sorry about that.